# What does ERROR_AZURE_DRIVE_DEV_PATH_NOT_SET mean?

Tags: azure

I am trying to attach a cloud drive as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg466226.aspx#bk_Storage but I get the error  ERROR_AZURE_DRIVE_DEV_PATH_NOT_SET ?

What does this mean? I've tripled checked my config at it seems ok.

I am trying to connect the cloud drive in a Windows Service on a VM Role.

Comment: Have you seen this post - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/10/07/handling-error-error-azure-drive-dev-path-not-set-when-mounting-a-cloud-drive.aspx?

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the FixMSI.js script from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg466226.aspx#bk_Install was failing. For some reason $(BuiltOutputPath) was empty. I did it relative to the $(ProjectDir) instead.

It then failed with a different error (and much earlier). CloudDriveException 0x80070103.
Searching for this gave me this article which basically told me to manually edit the driver inf file for the wa miniport. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh708321.aspx.

Now it attaches ok. The strange thing now is that the device has a warning when the vm starts (but only when hosted in azure), I have to manually go into the vm on azure and update the driver.

Answer (score 1):

try to change BuiltOutputPath to BuildOutputPath. According to Richard, this is an error in the document. Refer to the Community Content section on the document for more information.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference, plus it says '"$(BuiltOutputPath)" not "$(BuildOutputPath)"'.